# Double.TryParse returning negative

Tags: parsing, visual-studio-2008

I´m new in Visual Basic and I'm trying to do some easy stuff, but I got stuck when I tried to parse a string to double, I have debbuged and effectively the problem is the method Double.TryParse because always returns -1 as the converted double. If anyone point out what I'm doing wrong I will be grateful.

This is the class which calls the method that parses

```
Public Class Sumar
    Dim utilerias As Utilerias

    Public Function realizarSuma(ByVal Snum1 As String, ByVal Snum2 As String) As Double
        utilerias = New Utilerias()
        Dim num1, num2 As Double
        num1 = utilerias.parseStringToDouble(Snum1)
        num2 = utilerias.parseStringToDouble(Snum2)
        Return num1 + num2
    End Function

End Class
```

This is the method which parses

```
Public Function parseStringToDouble(ByVal Snum As String) As Double
        Dim num As Double
        num = Double.TryParse(Snum, num)
    Return num
End Function
```

Comment: Use Option Strict On for a while to flush these simple bugs out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of [`Double.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) indicates whether the parsing worked or not, it is a Boolean value. In your call, you're overwriting the result (which is in the second parameter passed by reference) with the return value. You would want something like this:

```
Public Function parseStringToDouble(ByVal Snum As String) As Double
    Dim num As Double
    If Not Double.TryParse(Snum, num) Then
        ' Report error. Input was not a number
    Return num
End Function
```

PS: Sorry, I'm not so fluent in VB syntax any more, but you'll get the concept...